# Generating json using spring-mvc

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I tried to generate a json response earlier using `spring-mvc (annotation)` . After so may failure i find out some check point :

1. I need to add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in my servelet mapper. although i don't know the reason.
2. Then I need to add `@ResponseBody` annotation which should bound the return value as http response as the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) says.
3. And I also need add some [jacson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/) dependency.

Did i missed something?
Now i have bunch of questions

1. why we have to add that in my servelet xml and how this whole process is working?
2. As `json` response is most commonly used when why spring need `jackson` dependency to generate json?

some days ago i was doing `Struts2` generating json response there was much simple.

3. Is there any way to do it more easily in spring-mvc .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should understand that `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` annotation used for many cases not only for generating json response in Spring. This annotation allow to use different annotations in Spring mvc classes like:`@NumberFormat @DateFormat @Controller @Valid` and of course `@ResponseBody`.
To generate json response you just need `@ResponseBody` annotation in your controller or servlet and import libraries for processing JSON. 
Recently java has oun set of APIs for processing JSON as part of Java EE 7 [JSR 353](https://jsonp.java.net/) actually it has clean [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp.htm).  Also you can use third party libraries like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). To process (parse, generate, transform, and query) JSON text it's necessarily to have one of this libs.
You can learn about most popular third party libraries and their performance in [this article](http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/top-7-open-source-json-binding-providers-available-today.html)

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/) you can see simple example.

Comment: with out this `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` tag all annoted part of my application work well except json part.

Comment: i understand that .. but why actually i need `jackson`? is there any way to avoid it.?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `jacson`  you can do something like:

**Your Model**

```
public class Shop {     
    String name;    
    String staffName[]; 
}
```

**Your Controller**
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/shop/list")
public class JSONController {

```
@RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {

    Shop shop = new Shop();
    shop.setName(name);
    shop.setStaffName(new String[]{"mkyong1", "mkyong2"});

    return shop;
}
```

}

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.mypackage" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Basically, you need check if:
Your Jackson library is existed in the project classpath

The mvc:annotation-driven is enabled

Return method annotated with @ResponseBody